# Update value from one table to other table after update trigger in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables permit_table with columns builder and permit_number
weekly_table with columns applicant and permit_number.
Now,if there is any update in builder column from permit_table, i need to update the applicantcolumn of weekly_table with 'old applicant value + new builder value' provided the permit number of the updated builder value from permit_table should match with the any permit number in weekly_table. 
I had tried with the below trigger and function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION edmonton.automated_builder_update_trigger_manual()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    e record;
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('Update weekly_table as a
set applicant = old.applicant||new.builder where old.permit_number = 
a.permit_number');


RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION edmonton.automated_builder_update_trigger_manual()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

And trigger is

```
CREATE TRIGGER builder_update_trigger_manual
AFTER UPDATE
ON edmonton.permit_table
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (old.builder IS DISTINCT FROM new.builder)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE edmonton.automated_builder_update_trigger_manual();
```

Am getting error 'Missing FROm CLAUSE entry for table 'old'.

Comment: Write the UPDATE directly in the body of the function to have OLD.* and NEW.* being interpolated. As opposed to passing the query to `EXECUTE` which is asking for no interpolation, which is the opposite of what you need and why the SQL looks for `old` as a real table.

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECUTE format('Update weekly_table as a
set applicant = old.applicant||new.builder where old.permit_number = 
a.permit_number');
```

try changing to:

```
EXECUTE format('Update weekly_table as a
set applicant = ($1).applicant||($2).builder where ($1).permit_number  = 
a.permit_number') using old,new;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this. Its raising an error 'COLUMN applicant not found in datatype permit_table'.Because applicant field will be available in weekly_table and not in permit_table.Any way to solve this?

Comment: and Daniels suggestion - just write update statement directly? should do the trick